# How to perform update using two table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I want to perform update operation by joining two different tables.

```
My tables are :

dim_sess

name                                        role
20111012133513aaa123                    
20110908072611aaa121        
20111002210235bbb853
20120113113353bbbl971
```

The role column is updated later.

and the other table is

```
employeerole
username           role             thedate
aaa         technician      2011-10-12 13:35:13
aaa         technician      2011-09-08 07:26:11
bbb         day guard       2011-10-02 21:02:35
bbb         day guard       2012-01-13 11:33:53
bbb         night guard     2012-01-13 21:30:00
```

I want to update role in the dim_sess table depending upon username and startdate. The same user can have different role in different date.  There is no common column in two table and the only column to perform join is "name" in dim_sess.

I write the following query to update the dim_ses table.

```
 UPDATE dim_sess
SET role = (SELECT employeerole.role FROM employeerole
WHERE SUBSTRING(dim_sess.name,15,7) = employeerole.username
AND SUBSTRING(dim_sess.name,1,14) = (TEXTCAT( TEXTCAT(TEXTCAT(SUBSTRING(thedate,1,4), SUBSTRING(thedate,6,2)) , TEXTCAT(SUBSTRING(thedate,9,2), SUBSTRING(thedate,12,2)) ), TEXTCAT(      SUBSTRING(thedate,15,2), SUBSTRING(thedate,18,2)))))
WHERE SUBSTRING(dim_sess.name,1,21) = (SELECT TEXTCAT((TEXTCAT(TEXTCAT(TEXTCAT(SUBSTRING(thedate,1,4), SUBSTRING(thedate,6,2)) , TEXTCAT(SUBSTRING(thedate,9,2), SUBSTRING(thedate,12,2))), TEXTCAT(SUBSTRING(thedate,15,2), SUBSTRING(thedate,18,2)))) , employeerole.username) AS session FROM employeerole);

The error message I get is:
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Since there is no common column between two tables, I try to join them by using the substring function to match the results. But this seems to be a bad solution. I was wondering if there is other way to join these two tables.

Comment: add a column to dim_sess like name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
update DIM_SESS DS
   set ROLE =
         (select ER.ROLE
            from EMPLOYEEROLE ER
           where substr(
                   DS.NAME
                  ,1
                  ,length(to_char(STARTDATE, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') || USERNAME)) like
                   to_char(STARTDATE, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') || USERNAME);
```

I've tested this in Oracle but I think you might be using PostgreSQL so the syntax might be a little different.

Comment: Yes I am using PostgresSQL. I got same error: "ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Comment: If you are getting that error then it suggests that you have duplicate entries in your EMPLOYEEROLE table. Try running the query `select USERNAME, STARTDATE, count(*) from EMPLOYEEROLE group by USERNAME, STARTDATE having count(*) > 1;` to find them. I would guess that duplicates of this sort shouldn't be allowed but if they are then you can change my sub-query to `select min(ER.ROLE)`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The only other solution I see to your problem is that you have a directly correlated field of data in your `dim_sess` table for `username`.  You could use a persisted computer column, and then do a `JOIN` on that column.  So your new `dim_sess` table definition could be something like this:

```
create table dim_sess
(
    name varchar(100),
    username as (SUBSTRING(name,15,7)) persisted,
    role varchar(100)
)
go
```

Comment: But I also need to check with startdate.The same user can have different role in different date.

Comment: @Rohita use your `JOIN` for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a correlated update with employeerole and a subquery extracting the fields from dim_sess.name plus their ctid (=unique row identifier) to join back to the rows to update. Correlated updates can be written in PG by adding a FROM clause followed by other tables or subqueries.
Also it has a regexp_matches function that makes it easier than all those substrings() calls. It returns an array whose 1->N elements are the captured substrings.

Code proposal:

```
UPDATE dim_sess d SET role=e.role
FROM employeerole e,
(SELECT t[1] as f1, t[2] as f2, t[3] as f3, i  from
 (select ctid as i, regexp_matches(name, E'^(\\d{14})([a-z]+)(\\d+)') AS t from dim_sess) s1
) s2
WHERE d.ctid=s2.i
AND to_char(e.thedate,'yyyymmddHH24MISS')=f1
AND e.username=f2
```